# Unable to run kubectl command on MacOS

Tags: kubernetes

I have just installed Kubernetes on my MacOS using homebrew.

Now, in the terminal, I ran `kubectl version` command and the error message reads `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 35.225.115.157:443: i/o timeout`

How to solve this issue?

Comment: I think you could not connect to kubernetes clusters. You may not configurate the kubernetes context, it automatically setup as usual when you install and create clusters. Please try to do step by step following this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-hello-istio/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)

Answer (score -2):

`kubectl version` makes a connection to both client and server (kubernetes master) in order to print the versions.

Run `kubectl cluster-info` and check if the server is up.